# Can't divide field by number in Sumo Logic

Tags: sumologic

I have a sumo logic query where i'm taking a numeric field and summing it, but that fields value is milliseconds so I want to divide the field by `1000` to get the number as seconds.

```
parse "DownloadDuration=*," as DownloadTime | sum(downloadtime / 1000) as TotalDownloadTime
```

but sumologic gives me an error: `Parse error: ')' expected but '/' found.` when i try to do this (even though their [help docs seem to suggest this is totally legit](http://help.sumologic.com/i19.69v2/Math_Expressions.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add another `parse` statement to alter the fields value.

```
parse "DownloadDuration=*," as DownloadTime | 
(downloadtime / 1000) as DownloadTime | 
sum(downloadtime) as TotalDownloadTime
```

Works perfectly!